# how to create multiple instances(Users) to firebird database for windows?

Tags: .net, database, firebird, embedded-database

Hi I have a issue with firebird database. I am using dotnet frame work. I had choosen firebird  database having embedded database and Lightweight, most important thing is ours is a portable software. I am unable change the default user password and unable to create a new User for the same database. In my program I have to change the default user(sysdba) password and create a new user to the same database.

Please give me the solutions for my program.

thanks And Regards

G V L Subrahmanyam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Firebird embedded, it does not use a username and password (although most drivers will require you to set a username and password (any will do)).

So you cannot change the username and password if you are using Firebird embedded, because there is no username and password to change.